# double is an integer, difficulty parsing

Tags: c#, int, double

This works perfectly, except that when the user enters an number with a decimal (e.g. `2.3`), it returns the same statement ("Number must be an integer").

I am trying to say if it is not an `int` OR a `double`.

Code:

```
while (true)
{
  Console.Write("Enter First Integer:");
  string line = Console.ReadLine();

  if (!int.TryParse(line, out firstNo)) //INT OR A DOUBLE
    Console.WriteLine("Number must be an integer. {0} is not an integer.", line);
  break;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear Integers are NOT Doubles

Comment: 2.3 is not an "integer with a decimal".  This is an integer with a decimal: "2.0"  So is this: "2.3E4".  But 2.3 is not a member of the set of integers.

Comment: @Jenny you use `while` loop and do `break` in the first iteration always. Are you sure you need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse it as `double`, it would work both with integers and decimals:

```
   double doubleVar;
   while (true)
   {
       Console.Write("Enter First number:");
       string line = Console.ReadLine();

       if (!double.TryParse(line, out doubleVar)) //PARSE INT OR DOUBLE
           Console.WriteLine("you must enter a number. {0} is not a number.", line);
       else
           break;
   }
```

Remember that `.` or `,` separator may differ depending on your current culture.

So, if you need to separate int ans doubles, do smth like this:

```
    if (int.TryParse(line, out intVar)) //PARSE INT
    {
          //it's int
    }
    else if (double.TryParse(line, out doubleVar)) //PARSE DOUBLE
    {
          //it's double  
    }
    else
    {
         //it's not
    }
```

Comment: Or parse it both ways and handle it differently if parsing as an integer fails.

Comment: @Skaperen It all depends on OP's real requirements. Of course it may vary, if it's, say, necessary to separate ints from doubles...In general, I agree

Answer (score 2):

Since all integers are doubles, you could just parse it as a double only.

Comment: Be nice to see some code (`if (!double.TryParse(line, out dblNum))` ?), but this was basically my thought as well. +1.

Answer (score 0):

try this simply trick,

```
bool result = line.Constains(".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole numbers and Fractional numbers are two different entities.You should not mix up.
If you are looking for a way to support fractional and whole number inputs then try below

```
if (!double.TryParse(line, out firstNo))
```